# How to stop returning [object, object]

Tags: javascript

I am looking at getting the elements of a drop down list when the items are checked but keep getting [Object Object] returned.

can someone please help me with the code I am using.

```
   var t = $("#serchTerm").val($(".dropdown-menu input[type='checkbox']:checked").map(function (){
    t = value = $(this).attr("data-val");
    $("#reportStatus").val(value);
    return t;
}));
```

Comment: `map()` will return you an array, what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Please, post your HTML and setup a working fiddle if possible. You should provide all the information necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you getting `[object, object]` or `[Object Object]` or (more likely) `[object Object]`? When you traced through your code, and stopped on the `t = value = ` line, what was the value of `this`? Why are you not spelling `searchTerm` correctly? Why are you using the form of `val()` which **sets** the value as input to `map`? Why are you setting `value` inside the function which you are already setting `t`? Do you realize you are trying to set the value of `reportStatus` again and again, each time through the loop? Do you know that `val` is used to set the value of input elements? Etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code is so broken it cannot possibly be fixed.

Comment: how about helping me fix it then?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `join()` since `map()` will return an array of jQuery objects.

I believe part of your issue is trying to condense your code too much and therefore not making it very readable

```
var valueArray = $(".dropdown-menu input[type='checkbox']:checked").map(function (){
    var t  = $(this).attr("data-val");
    //$("#reportStatus").val(value); removing this as it makes no sense
    return t;
}).get(); 

$("#serchTerm").val(valueArray.join());
```

This assumes you want a comma separated list of the values. Expected results were not given in question

Comment: need to provide some html and expected results. You haven't provided enough detail in question. Create  a demo in jsfiddle.net